# What is wrong with this Python Multiprocessing Code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to create some multiprocessing code for my project. I have created a snippet of the things that I want to do. However its not working as per my expectations. Can you please let me know what is wrong with this.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time

class A:
      def __init__(self,rpipe,spipe):
          print "In the function fun()"

      def run(self):
           print"in run method"
           time.sleep(5)
           message = rpipe.recv()
           message = str(message).swapcase()
           spipe.send(message)

 workers = []
 my_pipe_1 = Pipe(False)
 my_pipe_2 = Pipe(False)
 proc_handle = Process(target = A, args=(my_pipe_1[0], my_pipe_2[1],))
 workers.append(proc_handle)
 proc_handle.run()
 my_pipe_1[1].send("hello")
 message = my_pipe_2[0].recv()
 print message
 print "Back in the main function now"
```

The trace back displayed when i press ctrl-c:

```
 ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
 File "sim.py", line 22, in <module>
 message = my_pipe_2[0].recv()
 KeyboardInterrupt
```

When I run this above code, the main process does not continue after calling "proc_handle.run". Why is this?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I could not format it properly in this editor.

Comment: Do you get error messages of any kind?

Comment: what is "ph.run"?  I don't see that anywhere in the code...

Comment: Thanks for showing me multiprocessing.Pipe -- I had never seen that method of communicating between processes before.

Comment: `ph.run`  is `proc_handle.run()` I presume.

Comment: I am not getting any error message, the code is just waiting for recv to happen which never happens because, the send never gets executed. I am not sure why this is though.

Comment: `target=A` this is almost surely wrong. In this way when you start the new process it will simply create an instance of the class, but `A.run` wont be called at all...

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood how to use `Process`. You're creating a `Process` object, and passing it a class as `target`, but `target` is meant to be passed a callable (usually a function) that `Process.run` then executes. So in your case it's just instantiating `A` inside `Process.run`, and that's it.

You should instead make your `A` class a `Process` subclass, and just instantiate it directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time

class A(Process):
      def __init__(self,rpipe,spipe):
          print "In the function fun()"
          super(A, self).__init__()
          self.rpipe = rpipe
          self.spipe = spipe

      def run(self):
           print"in run method"
           time.sleep(5)
           message = self.rpipe.recv()
           message = str(message).swapcase()
           self.spipe.send(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    workers = []
    my_pipe_1 = Pipe(False)
    my_pipe_2 = Pipe(False)
    proc_handle = A(my_pipe_1[0], my_pipe_2[1])
    workers.append(proc_handle)
    proc_handle.start()
    my_pipe_1[1].send("hello")
    message = my_pipe_2[0].recv()
    print message
    print "Back in the main function now"
```

mgilson was right, though. You should call `start()`, not `run()`, to make `A.run` execute in a child process.

With these changes, the program works fine for me:

```
dan@dantop:~> ./mult.py 
In the function fun()
in run method
HELLO
Back in the main function now
```

Comment: Thanks dano, it helped me understand now. Is it the same way if I have to create a new thread too using threading.Thread? Will i have to just make class A inherit threading.Thread ?

Comment: @hemanths Yep, `Process` is designed to essentially be a drop-in replacement for `Thread`, so there's very few, if any, changes that need to be made when switching between the two.

Comment: @hemanths Though I'm not aware of a `threading` equivalent to `multiprocessing.Pipe`. You may want to use `Queue.queue` instead, should you switch to threads.

Comment: @dano: [dummy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) replicates the `Pipe` interface for threads.

Comment: @JoelCornett Ah, excellent, thanks. Looks like internally it implements `Pipe` using two `Queue.queue` instances. So @hemanths, you would need to switch `from multiprocessing import Pipe` to `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pipe` in addition to switching from `Process` to `Thread`. You could even just switch to `from multiprocessing.dummy import Process, Pipe`, and leave everything the same. `multiprocessing.dummy.Process` is just a wrapper around `threading.Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at this one, I think it's because you're calling [`proc_handle.run()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.run) instead of [`proc_handle.start()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.start).

The former is the activity that the process is going to do -- the latter actually arranges for `run` to be called on a separate process.  In other words, you're never forking the process, so there's no other process for `my_pipe_1[1]` to communicate with so it hangs.

Comment: Tried with `proc_handle.start()` too but no luck. Facing the same issue